# ignore composer post-autoload-dump errors

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to ignore when a post-autoload-dump command fails?
I want my deployment pipeline to still show up as successful, even if there is an error in one of the post-autoload-dump commands. (Removing the command is not an option)

Comment: Using the `--no-scripts` option?  Or another way if you use bash would be to simply ignore errors for that command `composer install ... || true`

Comment: What @JulienB. wrote, you can simply ignore the error (for an incremental build it is recommended to use `--no-plugins`  and `--no-scripts` in a composer pipeline anyway, perhaps for the same reason you encounter). you can further tweak this with `--no-autoloader` on `install` and have a dedicated `dump-autoload` step after it if you need to control things more fine-grained.